# Not select the "id" line from the json code

Tags: php, json

here I have a function to create a category. I need to select all subcategories and create a json code with them, and in it organized categories according to their subid

```
function unflattenArray($flatArray){
    $refs = array();
    $result = array();

    while(count($flatArray) > 0){
        for ($i=count($flatArray)-1; $i>=0; $i--){
            if ($flatArray[$i]["parent"]==0){
                $result[$flatArray[$i]["id"]] = $flatArray[$i];
                $refs = &$result[$flatArray[$i]["id"]];
                unset($flatArray[$i]);
                $flatArray = array_values($flatArray);
            }

            else if ($flatArray[$i]["parent"] != 0){
                if (array_key_exists($flatArray[$i]["parent"], $refs)){
                    $o = $flatArray[$i];
                    $refs[$flatArray[$i]["id"]] = $o;
                    $refs[$flatArray[$i]["parent"]]["subs"][] = &$refs[$flatArray[$i]["id"]];
                    unset($flatArray[$i]);
                    $flatArray = array_values($flatArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

this chooses this

```
{
    "17": {
        "id": 17,
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "XXX3"
    },
    "41": {
        "id": 41,
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "XXX2",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 45,
                "parent": 41,
                "title": "XXX7",
                "subs": [
                    {
                        "id": 102,
                        "parent": 45,
                        "title": "XXX10"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 101,
                        "parent": 45,
                        "title": "XXX9"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "85": {
        "id": 85,
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "XXX2"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "title": "XXX1",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 65,
                "parent": 1,
                "title": "XXX6"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I would need to select the same json, but without header !

```
{
        "17": { // <--- remove this ( "17": )
            "id": 17,
            "parent": 0,
            "title": "XXX3"
        },
        "41": {
            "id": 41,
            "parent": 0,
            "title": "XXX2",
            "subs": [
                {
                    .....
```

I can't delete the "id" line from the header, I only need a line with information

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$result[$flatArray[$i]["id"]] = $flatArray[$i];
```

to

```
$result[] = $flatArray[$i];
```

so it just appends to an indexed array instead of creating an associative array.

Comment: after that Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists(): Argument #2

Comment: I didn't look carefully enough -- there are other statements that expect this to be an associative array, so you can't just change this one line.

Answer (score 0):

why no apply array_values to $result var before return it?

```
function unflattenArray($flatArray){
...
return array_values($result);
}
```